# Flamelink CMS retrive data pure js

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, headless-cms, flamelink-cms

i am already setup firebase and flamelink
how i get data to manipulate from global i try this but it not work:

```
        var obj ={}
        app.content.get({schemaKey: 'berita'})
            .then((data) => {
                obj = data
                console.log("data" , data)
                console.log("object" , obj)
            })
            console.log("outsite", obj)
```

why output for obj different?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`app.content.get()` returns a Promise, so your `console.log('outsite, obj)` line runs before the query Promise is resolved.

You either need to work with the response data inside your `then` method or use `async-await` like this (from inside an `async` function):

```js
var obj = await app.content.get({schemaKey: 'berita'})
console.log("outsite", obj)
```